# Can a CORS Error be Related to Rate Limiting?

Tags: javascript, api, cors

I've been using a GET request to the [CoinGecko API](https://www.coingecko.com/en/api) and it is working about 95% of the time. 5% of the time, I start receiving CORS errors (and sometimes the CORS errors are followed by 429 errors). Since we are calling the API often to update prices, I'm wondering if the CORS error could be related to rate limiting rather than the code itself. The rate limit for their API is 10 requests per second per IP.

In the Network tab, the response shows a wildcard, which I believe means we don't need to modify our code as it relates to CORS (or maybe we do?)

[image: access-control-allow-origin header]

Any thoughts on this are appreciated, thanks

Comment: Sounds plausible to me

Comment: I'm getting the same issue with coingecko. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi @user2444499 ... thing is I seem to get that error every once in a while... it seems like most of the time I get the correct response from Gecko and a few times I get the CORS error.... If you are getting the CORS error all the time, it may be a different issue that you are having..

Comment: Thanks for the response @HRoark. No, I'm only getting it occasionally too. For now I've just wrapped my ajax call in a try / catch and I keep calling until the CORS error goes away again.